# Looping through JSON to place markers on a Google map

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to generate a google map using jQuery and javascript. The values for latitude and longitude are stored in a JSON file. When the user clicks the state  name the needs to get generated.

The problem with my code is that a graph is getting genrated for only `index[0]`. My for loop is not working appropriately. A graph for New York is generated but it points to Nepal rather than New York. Here is my code:

```
for (var i in data.universitylist) {
    var lat = data.universitylist[i].lat;
    var lng = data.universitylist[i].lng;

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {
            lat: lat,
            lng: lng
        },
        scrollwheel: false,
        zoom: 8
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: {
            lat: lat,
            lng: lng
        },
        title: 'Hello World!'
    });
};
```

The JSON file:

```
var data = {
    "universitylist": [{
            "Name": "Columbia University",
            "City": "New York",
            "State": "NY",
            "lat": 40.7127,
            "lng": 74.0059
        },{
            "Name": "Stanford University",
            "City": "Stanford,",
            "State": "CA",
            "lat": 37.0000,
            "lng": 120.0000
        },{
            "Name": "Duke University",
            "City": "Durham",
            "State": "NC",
            "lat": 35.5000,
            "lng": 80.0000
        },{
            "Name": "University of Pennsylvania",
            "City": "Philadelphia",
            "State": "PA",
            "lat": 41.0000,
            "lng": 77.5000
        },{
            "Name": "Northcentral University",
            "City": "Prescott Valley",
            "State": "AZ",
            "lat": 34.0000,
            "lng": 112.0000
        },{
            "Name": "Johns Hopkins University",
            "City": "Baltimore",
            "State": "MD",
            "lat": 39.0000,
            "lng": 76.7000
        }, {
            "Name": "Northwestern University",
            "City": "Evanston",
            "State": "IL",
            "lat": 40.0000,
            "lng": 89.0000
        },{
            "Name": "Rice University",
            "City": "Houston",
            "State": "TX",
            "lat": 31.0000,
            "lng": 100.0000
        },{
            "Name": "University of Southern California",
            "City": "Los Angeles",
            "State": "CA",
            "lat": 37.0000,
            "lng": 120.0000
        },{
            "Name": "Georgia Institute of Technology",
            "City": "Atlanta",
            "State": "GA",
            "lat": 32.9605,
            "lng": 83.1132
        }
    ]
};
```

Comment: The code you have now is working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/f4ksqyz5/. Can you show an example of the issue in a http://jsfiddle.net. If the marker is being placed in the wrong place then it sounds just like your lat/lng values are incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you are re-generating the map for every iteration within the `for` loop.

Try taking it outside, and change your `for in` to a `for`:-

```js
var data = {
  "universitylist": [{
    "Name": "Columbia University",
    "City": "New York",
    "State": "NY",
    "lat": 40.7127,
    "lng": 74.0059
  }, {
    "Name": "Stanford University",
    "City": "Stanford,",
    "State": "CA",
    "lat": 37.0000,
    "lng": 120.0000
  }, {
    "Name": "Duke University",
    "City": "Durham",
    "State": "NC",
    "lat": 35.5000,
    "lng": 80.0000
  }, {
    "Name": "University of Pennsylvania",
    "City": "Philadelphia",
    "State": "PA",
    "lat": 41.0000,
    "lng": 77.5000
  }, {
    "Name": "Northcentral University",
    "City": "Prescott Valley",
    "State": "AZ",
    "lat": 34.0000,
    "lng": 112.0000
  }, {
    "Name": "Johns Hopkins University",
    "City": "Baltimore",
    "State": "MD",
    "lat": 39.0000,
    "lng": 76.7000
  }, {
    "Name": "Northwestern University",
    "City": "Evanston",
    "State": "IL",
    "lat": 40.0000,
    "lng": 89.0000
  }, {
    "Name": "Rice University",
    "City": "Houston",
    "State": "TX",
    "lat": 31.0000,
    "lng": 100.0000
  }, {
    "Name": "University of Southern California",
    "City": "Los Angeles",
    "State": "CA",
    "lat": 37.0000,
    "lng": 120.0000
  }, {
    "Name": "Georgia Institute of Technology",
    "City": "Atlanta",
    "State": "GA",
    "lat": 32.9605,
    "lng": 83.1132
  }]
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  center: {
    lat: 33,
    lng: 100
  },
  scrollwheel: false,
  zoom: 3
});

for (var i = 0; i < data.universitylist.length; i++) {
  var lat = data.universitylist[i].lat;
  var lng = data.universitylist[i].lng;

  console.log(i, lat, lng);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: {
      lat: lat,
      lng: lng
    },
    title: 'Hello World!'
  });
};
```

```css
#map {
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply....:) But the thing is you are storing json data within the script part other than putting it as an external json file.You are absolutely correct but when I was trying to fetch latitude and longitude from ext json file, I was not getting result